# Convert from "TimeSpan" to "Long"

Tags: c#, .net, casting, long-integer

How can I convert a `timespan` datatype to a `long`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you use .NET, 
Use:

```
MyTimeSpan.Ticks()
```

and to convert back (sample in VB.NET, C# implementation is trivial nontheless):

```
MyTimeSpan = New TimeSpan(totalTicks)
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you must use

```
MyTimeSpan.Ticks;
```

instead

```
MyTimeSpan.Ticks();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you would to accomplish, but TimeSpan has some static fields:

```
    long ticks = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;

    Console.WriteLine(ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour);
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
```

you can also get another double values like:

TimeSpan nearlyFiveDays = TimeSpan.FromDays(5) - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

```
Console.WriteLine(nearlyFiveDays.TotalDays);          // 4,99998842592593
Console.WriteLine(nearlyFiveDays.TotalHours);         // 119,999722222222
Console.WriteLine(nearlyFiveDays.TotalMinutes);       // 7199,98333333333
Console.WriteLine(nearlyFiveDays.TotalSeconds);       // 431999
Console.WriteLine(nearlyFiveDays.TotalMilliseconds);  // 431999000
```